# React onClick works on reload but not on actual click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

all you need is line 13, I guess the syntax is correct but when I reload the page it's alerting 2 times without me clicking the button and then when I click it it doesn't do anything

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import { FullPage, Slide } from 'react-full-page';
import First from './First';

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <FullPage controls>
      <Slide>
        <h1>Inner slide content</h1>
        <First name="Nairi" count={count} />
        <button onClick={alert()} className="btn btn-dark">+</button>
        {/* <button onClick={setCount(count - 1)} className="btn btn-dark">-</button> */}
      </Slide>
      <Slide>
        <h1>Another slide content</h1>
      </Slide>
    </FullPage>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: () => alert(). The handler should be a function, not the result of the function. The same principle applies to the second onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below here ! You are immediately calling `alert` function as the component initially renders. That's not a right way to set a `onClick` in react.

```
<button onClick={alert()} className="btn btn-dark">+</button>
```

You need to do:) Since it is an `alert` function of javascript.

```
<button onClick={()=>alert()} className="btn btn-dark">+</button>
```

In general case, we just need to use function name without using `()` to set our event handler.

For example: You can create a seperate function named `handleClick` and cal your alert within that.

```
<button onClick={handleClick} className="btn btn-dark">+</button>

const handleClick = ()=>{
   alert() 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your syntax of writing alert is wrong
correct one is this

```
<button onClick= {()=> alert()} className="btn btn-dark">+</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass a callback function not an actual function. in your code, alert function will run anytime you refresh the page and the browser reaches line 13 for compilation. you have to use `onClick={alert}` or `onClick={() => alert()}` instead.